# How can I Update this $s var in PHP (LARAVEL)?

Tags: laravel-8, php-8

I'm using :
PHP 8.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2021 14:12:19)
and LARAVEL 8.

I don't know for some reason after pushing element to `$s`, the `$s` (outside loop) wont update it's value to `["...",".","ok"]`. I'm using `Illuminate\Support\Arr::exists()` to check if the value already added to `$s`. I keep getting `["...",".","ok","ok","ok"]`. What i want is `["...",".","ok"]`. Is anyone know what im doing is wrong?
Thanks.

```js
public function showImportForm(){ // ignore this
        if ($_SESSION['current'] == session_id()) { // ignore this
            $s = array("...", ".");
            for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
                if(!Arr::exists($s, "ok")){
                    $s[] = "ok";
                }else{
                    print("skip");
                }
            }
            return $s;
            //return view('database.import');
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not use `in_array`?

Comment: actualy i tried to import excel to DB but i want to get unique record from excel rows... like [ADMIN, ADMIN, ADMIN, HRD, HRD] but i want just [ADMIN, HRD].  this code just for test to simulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a look at the definition of [`Arr::exists`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Collections/Arr.php#L139):

> Determine if the given key exists in the provided array.

That method does not check whether the **value** is already present in the array. Use `in_array` instead